# Deep copy of a pandas panel?

Tags: pandas, deep-copy

When I try to copy a pandas panel object using the [instructions provided in the online documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.copy.html), I do not get the expected bahavior.

Maybe this will illustrate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

# make first panel with some bogus numbers 
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('EFGH'))
pnl = {} 
pnl['alpha'] = df1
pnl['beta'] = df2

# copy pnl into pnl2
# according to online docs the default is 'deep=True'
# but it chokes when I try to specify deep=True 
pnl2 = pnl.copy()


# now delete column C from pnl2['alpha']
del pnl2['alpha']['C']



#Now when I try to find column C in the original panel (pnl) it's gone!
```

I figure there must be a slick solution to this, but I couldn't find it in the online docs, nor in Wes McKinney's book (my only book on pandas...).

Any tips/advise much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't make a Panel, just a dict of DataFrames.  Add this line to convert it to a Panel object, and it should work as you expect.

```
pnl = pd.Panel(pnl)
```

Comment: DOH! Thank you. Writing programs is turning out to be a potent aid in the cultivation of humility.